# Angular2 - Pass router param as variable to ngForm

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Just having a bit of difficulty passing a router param (id) to an ngForm and then to an event emitter. Here is how I get the id - as you can see the first console.log works fine, i can get the id from the router. Now I am trying to assign this to my singleOpenHome object (but get an undefined error):

```
@Input() singleOpenHome: OpenHomeModel;

ngOnInit() {
        // Get the slug on it from the router
        this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            let id = params['propertyID'];
            console.log('id on the child is:'+id);
            //this.singleOpenHome.propertyID == id; Cannot read property 'propertyID' of undefined
        });
    }
```

Now i am wanting to pass this to a form:

```
 <form class="my2" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="handleSubmit(form.value, form.valid)" novalidate></form>
```

Here is my event emmitter:

```
@Output()
    update: EventEmitter<OpenHomeModel> = new EventEmitter<OpenHomeModel>();

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    handleSubmit(sinlgeOpenHome: OpenHomeModel, isValid: boolean) {
        if (isValid) {
            this.update.emit(sinlgeOpenHome);
        }
    }
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Does all the code you showed belong to the same component? If yes, just assign the route param to a class property — `this.id = params['propertyID'];` — then you can access the property from anywhere in the component or its template.

Comment: Tried this: this.singleOpenHome.propertyID = params['propertyID']; But i cant show the value in the template like {{ singleOpenHome.propertyID }} wont work.

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you try the code I suggested? Does all the code you showed belong to the same component?

Comment: Yes all the same component. Where should I put the this.id... inside my ngOnInit?

Comment: Yes. `let id = ...` becomes `this.id = ...`. You'll also need to declare the `id` property on the class.

Comment: Got it - well this will work for me, i can bind that value to a hidden input and post my data now thank you

Comment: You should fix the bugs in your code. Using `==` instead of `=` is a serious semantic error. I suggest you get a linter and dial up the TypeScript strictness and reread your code

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced problems specifically related to converting the `route.params` `Observable` into a `Promise` which is what `forEach` does. Consider simply using `subscribe`

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Get the slug on it from the router
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    const id = params['propertyID'];
    console.log(`id on the child is: ${id}`);
  });
}
```

This looks line like a typo

```
this.singleOpenHome.propertyID == id;
```

You're performing a comparison instead of an assignment.

That said you may have other bugs which lead to the property being undefined. Since it's marked as an input I assume it comes from an external binding. Make sure the value that you are passing into this binding is properly initialized.

Comment: You are so right - I haven't done my bindings correctly, I have a parent container which should initialize the singleOpenHome object and pass it into it's child component, then I can assign the propertyID variable (but I will pass it in with binding from the parent)